# Outlook Calendar View Settings

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

How do I remove the parallel line running between each day in the screenshot below please? Also you’ll note there is two entries on the 8th, one all day as Test1 and the other as Test2 which is has set times. This also is annoying as I can’t see the name of the Test2 one like the one above.

[image: OLK Calendar View]

Comment: What have you researched or tried so far? Have you tried resetting views?

Comment: Hi, yes reset the current view with no change

Comment: Anybody else have any ideas?